# Error while removing items from NSUserDefaults with tableView swipe function

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsuserdefaults

*I trie to remove items from NSUserDefaults with tableView swipe function. But when I test my App it always crashes after clicking "delete".*

**defining the variable and loading the data back from NSUserDefaults:**

```
 var exercises:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
```

...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var exercisesListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("exercisesList") as? NSMutableArray

    if ((exercisesListFromUserDefaults) != nil){
        exercises = exercisesListFromUserDefaults!
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

**delete functions:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        self.deleteItem(exercises[indexPath.row])

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}

func deleteItem(sender: AnyObject) {
    exercises.removeObject(sender)

    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(exercises, forKey: "exercisesList")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

*Edit:* **Error:**

(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x190c34, 0x0000000108715282 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000108715282 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001087484c3 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x00000001084a519a libsystem_sim_c.dylib`abort + 129
    frame #3: 0x0000000108759481 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 257
    frame #4: 0x00000001087813d5 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 267
    frame #5: 0x0000000107c1de19 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 103
    frame #6: 0x000000010877eb01 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x000000010877e7aa libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x0000000107c1dd2c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x000000010600453e CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 654
    frame #10: 0x000000010a1d09f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #11: 0x0000000106965420 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
  * frame #12: 0x0000000105ee2c5e Progress`top_level_code + 78 at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #13: 0x0000000105ee2c9a Progress`main + 42 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #14: 0x00000001083f7145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

Comment: Show the line it crashes on, the exception message and the stack trace

Comment: Look at my edited post. Do you mean this?

Comment: Close, though that doesn't tell us the line it crashes on or what type of exception.

Comment: I'm new with swift so can you please tell me where I could find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
var exercisesListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("exercisesList") as? NSMutableArray
```

is a problem because the array will not be mutable. User defaults always returns immutable objects. You need to make a mutable array (copy) of this array before you can change it and store it back into user defaults.

```
var myMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: myImmutableArray)
```

Comment: Like this?

NSArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray];

Comment: That's obj-c, and should all reference `NSMutableArray`, not `NSArray`, but yes in purpose